# jQuery ui auto complete with json File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I am trying to fetch the data from the JSON file jquery ui autocomplete is not working . This is my JSON array

```
[
 {
   "FIELD1": "A",
   "FIELD2": "B",
   "FIELD3": "C"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "ITEM ",
   "FIELD2": "RATE LIST",
   "FIELD3": "HSN Code"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "HORSES - PURE-BRED BREEDING ANIMALS ",
   "FIELD2": "0.12",
   "FIELD3": "1011010"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "ASSES - PURE-BRED BREEDING ANIMALS ",
   "FIELD2": "0",
   "FIELD3": "1011020"
 }]
```

i am trying to fetch these results in jquery ui autocomplete but it is not working

```
 $( function() {
  $('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("check.json?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
            response($.map(data.dealers, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value,
                    value: key
                };
            }));
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
});
  } );
```

Comment: Did you try to change your json propperty names with label and value like "label", "value"

Comment: can you please make an answer for me :)

Comment: Calling GET on `"check.json?term=" + request.term` will result in 100% of the results. Unless your web server has server side processing of .json files, it's not going to know what to do with `term`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot change the JSON file, I would advise:

```
source: function (request, response) {
  $.getJSON("check.json", function (data) {
    var results = [];
    console.log("Data:", data);
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
      console.log("Checking if", request.term, "is part of", v.FIELD1);
      if(v.FIELD1.indexOf(request.term) == 0){
        console.log("True");
        results.push({
          label: v.FIELD1,
          value: v.FIELD2,
          hsn: v.FIELD3,
          oData: v
        });
      } else {
        console.log("False");
      }
    });
    console.log("Sending results:", results);
    response(results);
  });
}
```

This will pull in all of the result since it's JSON and not a server side scripting file. You will then need to hunt out the request term. This is where `$.each()` is helpful. You can also use `$.ui.autocomplete.filter()` too. For this case, it's not as useful since it requires an array and term to filter for.

**UPDATE**

After I saw your Fiddle, I forked it into a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uejaafuk/

**JavaScript**

```
var myData = [{
  "FIELD1": "A",
  "FIELD2": "B",
  "FIELD3": "C"
}, {
  "FIELD1": "ITEM ",
  "FIELD2": "RATE LIST",
  "FIELD3": "HSN Code"
}, {
  "FIELD1": "HORSES - PURE-BRED BREEDING ANIMALS ",
  "FIELD2": "0.12",
  "FIELD3": "1011010"
}, {
  "FIELD1": "ASSES - PURE-BRED BREEDING ANIMALS ",
  "FIELD2": "0",
  "FIELD3": "1011020"
}];

$(function() {
  $('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      //$.getJSON("check.json", function(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
          json: JSON.stringify(myData)
        },
        url: "/echo/json/",
        success: function(data) {
          var results = [];
          console.log("Data:", data);
          $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            console.log("Checking if", request.term, "is part of", v.FIELD1);
            if (v.FIELD1.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
              console.log("True");
              results.push({
                label: v.FIELD1,
                value: v.FIELD2,
                hsn: v.FIELD3,
                oData: v
              });
            } else {
              console.log("False");
            }
          });
          console.log("Sending results:", results);
          response(results);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
  });
});
```

Comment: i am creating a fiddle wait

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra edited - found  the missing `)` at the end of `$.each()`

Comment: i have tried this code but nothing is working this code is not showing any response but it is giving status 200

Comment: Ok, so the 200 is good, when you review your Network section, do you see the JSON data in the response to the AJAX call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147975/discussion-between-tayyab-gulsher-vohra-and-twisty).